# Giving Error String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, datetime-format

Well I've tried following:

```
IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);

DateTime DateTo;
string DateToStr = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
DateTo = DateTime.ParseExact(DateToStr, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", culture);
```

Also tried following:

```
DateTime DateTo;
string DateToStr = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
DateTo = DateTime.ParseExact(DateToStr, "yyyy-MM-dd", culture);
```

And following also:

```
DateTime DateTo;
string DateToStr = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
DateTo = DateTime.ParseExact(DateToStr, "yyyy-M-dd HH:mm:ss", culture);
```

Each time it is giving me the same error:

***String was not recognized as a valid DateTime***

Whats going wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you use `Parse()` method?

Comment: Not working in my case. :(

Comment: Check the string passed and format they should match. For example, if string is 4/10/2014 the format should be "M/dd/yyyy" instead of "MM/dd/yyyy"

Answer (score 0):

Try calling it with additional parameter

```
DateTo = DateTime.ParseExact(DateToStr, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", culture, DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces);
```